# Automatic Fade in and out of scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fade

Is there a way to activate a fade animation every time the game changes from one scene to the other, without the user doing somthing specific like hiting a pre-determined key?
Basically the transtions needs to start just because there is a change in scenes.

I have a bunch of scenes and i need to add a fade to black transition between them.
All tutorials i found need some specific key input or something happening while i only have a few videos with no possible interaction with the user (in most cases).

Just in case that's not possible (or inpractical for rookies) I guess i could hook up the animations to the user pushing buttons that send you to other scenes (could use help with that aswell). And the first scene could work with a timer/delay.

*Unity and visual studio update to latest stable builds.

Comment: One solution would be to create a script which controls the changing of scenes, and it will calls these fades; this way you will always use it instead of directly calling `SceneManager` and you'll get your fades. Also, you should probably create the effect in a separate scene and load it additively or mark it with `DontDestroyOnLoad`

Answer (score 2):

So every time you need to change scene you actually need to first fade-out your screen, then run scene change and after new scene is loaded - fade screen in. You can do it like that:

1) Create new Canvas object in start scene of your project. Set canvas mode to "**Screen Space - Overlay**" and make sure **Sort Order** is set high enough so your canvas will be on top always.

[new Canvas object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4nMs.png)

2) Create an empty Image on this Canvas and size it so it covers all the scree. Set Color to transparent. Dont forget to toggle "**Raycast Target**" of image off (or you won't be able to mouseclick through it)

[new Image object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWofK.png)

3) Add this script to your Canvas object:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum FadeStatus
    {
        fading_id,
        fading_out,
        none
    }

    public static SceneChanger Instance;
    public Image fadeImage;
    public float fadeDuration;

    private FadeStatus currentFadeStatus = FadeStatus.none;
    private float fadeTimer;
    private string sceneToLoad;

    void Start()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            Instance = this;

            SceneManager.sceneLoaded += OnSceneLoaded;
        }
        else
            Destroy(gameObject);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }


    void OnSceneLoaded(Scene scene, LoadSceneMode mode)
    {
        //scene loaded, running fade-in
        currentFadeStatus = FadeStatus.fading_id;
    }

    public void ChangeScene(string _name)
    {
        sceneToLoad = _name;
        currentFadeStatus = FadeStatus.fading_out;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(currentFadeStatus != FadeStatus.none)
        {
            fadeTimer += Time.deltaTime;

            if(fadeTimer > fadeDuration) //done fading
            {
                fadeTimer = 0;

                if (currentFadeStatus == FadeStatus.fading_out)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneToLoad);
                    fadeImage.color = Color.black;
                }
                else
                    fadeImage.color = Color.clear;

                currentFadeStatus = FadeStatus.none;
            }
            else //still fading
            {
                float alpha = 0;
                if (currentFadeStatus == FadeStatus.fading_out)
                    alpha = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, fadeTimer / fadeDuration);
                else
                    alpha = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, fadeTimer / fadeDuration);

                fadeImage.color = new Color(0, 0,0, alpha);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Go back to Editor and assign your transparent Image to its field on SceneChanger script and adjust fadeDuration (time of one fade in seconds)

5) Now you can change scenes from code using

```
SceneChanger.Instance.ChangeScene("YourSceneName");
```

6) Don't forget to add all needed scenes to build settings, otherwise it won't work.

[build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiDz2.png)

7) You **DON'T** need to add SceneChanger on other scenes, it will be saved between scenes due to DontDestroyOnLoad().